# How make a view of thumbnails in landscape mode?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a view with the task to show a bunch of images (similar to the photos app).

In the top area is the full-size image and in the bottom a list of images.

Let's say exist 100 images. Now the user is on the 15-20 image section and is on the image 16.

Now, my problem is how aproach this. I wanna something that work like the UITableView control but in landscape mode...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should still be able to use a UITableView for your scrolling list of images, if I understand your needs properly.  You want to have a scrolling list of single images along the bottom of the screen, like you see in something like Aperture.

To do this, create a UITableView and rotate it 90 degrees using a CGAffineTransform.  For example, the following code creates a table, rotates it, and places it at the bottom of the screen:

```
UITableView *imageTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(215.0f, 30.0f, 50.0f, 480.0f)];
imageTable.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0f);
[self.view addSubview:imageTable];
```

You then could simply place your images in the table rows using each row cell's image property (remembering to rotate the images 90 degrees in the opposite direction of the table view).

Answer (score -1):

In landscape mode you are on your own.

Wouldn't really be that hard to do using a grid of UIImageViews.

Memory might be an issue, so you would have to page through the array and only instantiate the UIImageViews you want to show.

Sounds like fun! Good luck!