# Better way to have a photo slider/thumbnails on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have a probaly large list of images and want something like the photo app but with custom toolbar.

I wonder how do this. I see the sample of Apple http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Scrolling/index.html but that not will work for a large set of images.

I have a product list and some of my customer need download as much as 12,000 products in the device (I have a solution for the PocketPC I'm porting to iPhone).

In this thread [How make a view of thumbnails in landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530045/how-make-a-view-of-thumbnails-in-landscape-mode) somebody suggest is possible use a TableView, but then I'm not sure... mainly how hide the section caption then could be...

**UPDATED** correct the link

Answer (score 2):

The "Scrolling" demo won't work as-is for a large image set, but some minor adjustments can easily fix that.  The trick is to use UIScrollView delegate methods to load images on demand and then unload them after they disappear.  For decent performance you'd want the central image and one or two on either side to be loaded-- meaning that you can extend that design to support as many images as you like but still never have more than 3-5 in memory at a time.

The Stackoverflow link you post doesn't actually mention table views, so I'm not sure what approach you have in mind there.  If by "section caption" you're referring to section header and/or footer text, then just don't provide any.  Table views don't have a default for this, so if you don't give one to a table view then it won't show one.