# Thumbnail view of images

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to show some images as a thumbnail in View controller but i dont know how to do this. Can anyone please give me some ideas or sample code if possible.

Comment: Do you ever vote/mark answers as accepted??

Answer (score 36):

Are you asking how to create thumbnails from larger images, or about how to build a view controller which displays them nicely?

**Building a view controller:**

You could use `TTPhotoViewController` from [the Three20 project](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) ([description](http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/)), which acts similarly to the iPhone's built in camera roll to view images.

You can look at [the `Scrolling` sample code](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Scrolling/index.html) from apple, referred to in [this question about using it for thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652644/better-way-to-have-a-photo-slider-thumbnails-on-iphone).

If you want to build one yourself, you might consider using a [`GridView`](http://bynomial.com/moriarty/GridView.h.txt) from [the moriarty library](http://bynomial.com/moriarty/), either as a large grid in a `UIScrollView`, or on a more efficient row-by-row basis in a `UITableView`.  There's a previous question on [optimized image loading in a `UIScrollView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098234/optimized-image-loading-in-a-uiscrollview).

**Creating thumbnails from larger images:**

The code-easiest way to scale down an image is to simply display it in a `UIImageView` with a frame set to the smaller size that you want - it's scaled for you.

If you want to save a thumbnail, or care about memory usage, you can create a hard-scaled version.  The sample code below is taken from [this blog post](http://ofcodeandmen.poltras.com/2008/10/30/undocumented-uiimage-resizing/), and can be added to `UIImage` as a category method:

```
- (UIImage*) imageScaledToSize: (CGSize) newSize {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
  [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
  UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return newImage;
}
```

Finally, here's a previous question on [masking out round corners on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996292/how-to-mask-a-square-image-into-an-image-with-round-corners-in-the-iphone-sdk), similar to the app icons used on the home screen.

*Added*

**Using an image's built-in thumbnail:**

There's a nice function called `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` that understands built-in thumbnails in certain image data formats.  You can see some useful sample code for this under *Creating a Thumbnail Image from an Image Source* in [the Image I/O Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-DontLinkElementID_5) from Apple.

Comment: This does not maintain even a little bit of aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: @Shailesh, by specifying the newSize of the image, the resulting aspect ratio is completely up to you. You can preserve the old aspect ratio, for example, by choosing a float "scale" so that oldSize.width * scale and oldSize.height * scale both fit into the room available for the thumbnail, and then effectively setting newSize = oldSize * scale.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with thumbnails; perhaps you could clarify which ones you are most concerned about?

1. How to display a smaller version of an existing image
2. How to speed up paging by caching the thumbnails (instead of just dynamically shrinking the originals)
3. How to allow the user to page through the thumbnails
4. How to synchronize the thumbnails with the originals, in the event that your images are editable or the user can add to them