# How do I create a thumbnail view in my UIView?

Tags: iphone

I want to add a thumbnail picture viewer to my application.I have been trying to do in many ways but didn't succeeded in anyway.I'm quite new to iPhone development.can anyone please help?....

I'm currently creating a UIImageView with CGRectMake and adding an image to it and changing the position of the UIImageView.

What I want to know is what is the standard procedure to make a thumbnail view?....and can anyone please direct me to a sample code which will help me to sort this problem????....

http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3432/3378117315_3bf905bdb6_o.jpg

Above image shows how I want my view to be displayed.....

Thank You.....

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215869/thumbnail-view-of-images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm, since you're using the [`TTPhotoViewController`](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTPhotoViewController.h) from the [Three20 project](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20) as your example of what you want this to do, why not either a) use that class in your app, or b) use its code as an example of how to implement that sort of thing?

Comment: I dnt understand the Three20 Structure.so i skipped it.
Anyway I got it cleared.
Thanks Sixten...